# How can I remove specific consecutive symbols except the last occurrence in a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JS function which passes a string into JS's eval() function. If the function is passed a string which has consecutive characters such as 10*+-+10*-/5, I want to replace consecutive characters except the last consecutive character so it would look like 10+10/5. If the last consecutive character is a '-', then I want to ignore that character, e.g. 10*-10 should equal -100 rather than be evaluated as 10-10 = 0. This is the regex pattern I have so far:

```
var filtered = this.state.input.match(/(\*|\+|\/|-)?\d+/g).join('');
```

Comment: Please show us the js code with the regex you tried, so that we can help you improve it.

Comment: I've edited the original question

Comment: Ad a side note, it’s ok if you’re doing this for practice but you shouldn’t use eval for real work. Parse the expression or use existing third-party lib that can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex: `(\*|\+|\/|-)?\d+`, which will match a number and the preceding symbol.

```js
const str = '10*+-+10*-/5';

const fn = (s) =>
   s.match(/(\*|\+|\/|-)?\d+/g).join('');

console.log(fn(str));
```

Comment: This works, however, I now have a new problem, where 10*-10 will return 10-10 i.e. 0 instead of -100, so I want it to ignore the - if it is the last consecutive symbol.

Comment: @Spartan123 Is there some specified condition when to include `-` and when do not?

Comment: I've managed to resolve this by modifying the regex pattern slightly to /(\*|\+|\/|-)?(\.|\-)?\d+/g